# Problems with php-gd in php8.1

Tags: php-gd

I have php8.1 running on FreeBSD 12.

Install php81-gd and having a trouble to start php due to the following error:

Any guess how to fix it, please?

````php
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/20210902/gd.so (/usr/local/lib/php/20210902/gd.so: Undefined symbol "gdImageCreateFromAvif"), /usr/local/lib/php/20210902/gd.so.so (Cannot open "/usr/local/lib/php/20210902/gd.so.so")) in Unknown on line 0```
````

Comment: Also on other distros: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/runs/7318103136?check_suite_focus=true#step:8:11

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to upgrade the `libgd` package as well with `pkg upgrade libgd`; for whatever reason the package manager doesn’t seem to do it automatically when you install the `php81-gd` package.